# Where are the implementations of the C libraries?

Tags: c, libraries, libm

I want to know how `C` library implements the `sqrt()` function. I got the header file `math.h` in `/usr/include`. But where is the actual implementation? I am doing a numerical computation project and would like to see the implementations of all the functions available in `math.h`.

Comment: `Googling gives no good results whatsoever`-- somehow I don't believe that. Pardon me.

Comment: And see also [Implementation of ceil() and floor()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208488/implementation-of-ceil-and-floor)

Comment: On linux: `man sqrt` tells me to link `-lm`, meaning `libm`, short for libmath. Most often these are part of glibc (GNU libc) which is the "standard" C library in most linux distributions. It's not likely that your distro by default provides the source for it installed on your computer, but a pre-compiled shared library. To get the source the best way is to go to the webpage for the library. Google `GNU C Library` and you shall find.

Comment: Best advice is given in  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5233569/2564301

Comment: While from your question it can be inferred that you're talking about Linux, it would be a good idea to tag your question appropriately so there's no room for doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a generic answer for your query in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233569/2173917).

However, to be specific to this question, to get the *math* related functions, you need to search `libm` source code inside `glibc`. That is present in the directory named `math`.

An online browsable version is [available here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/).

Comment: The GNU C library **do** contain math functions, you just have to link them in specifically if needed.

Comment: @Jite Yeah, I updated the wording. I realized the wrong meaning after writing. Thanks.

Comment: Well the source code is still just in one repository so your wording is still a bit confusing. You'd more likely look for math functions in the math folder (although it might not be obvious exactly where stuff are implemented).

Comment: English is not my native language either, but I think in this case it's not about the language itself but rather that you try to hide a lack of knowledge by blaiming the language. As I wrote in my comment to the author the `man` pages are often a good start to find out where things come from. In this case it's most likely in the `glibc` source code, that can be found by googling. We now also know it's a math function and the source code contains a math folder, so it's most likely there. `libm` in this case is just a library object put together from certain pieces of glibc.

Comment: @Jite I did not blame the language, I know it's my fault not knowing the proper wordings and a very bad excuse (as you _may_ find) but it is what it is. However, I don't think we should be discussing it here anyway. I have updated my answer with a link to the same, if you kindly review and confirm, it will be helpful. Thank you fro your time.

Comment: It would be enough to say that he/she should search for the implementation in the glibc source folder and that math functions *most likely* (unless you know for sure) reside in the math folder.